# How to display read more text in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have inserted more tag in my content but the read more link is not showing up in my home page.

```
<?php
$queryArr = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'offset' => $offset,
);
$posts = get_posts($queryArr);
foreach ($posts as $post){
     the_content('Read More');
     echo $post->post_excerpt;
     echo $post->post_content;
}
?>


the_content('Read More');
echo $post->post_excerpt;
echo $post->post_content;
```

none of these three is showing up read more button.How can i solve this problem?

Comment: instead of using the_content() you can use the_excerpt and if you want to customize the read more text then you can use the function..
// Replaces the excerpt "more" text by a link
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
 return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Read the full article...</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Comment: I was not able to push a return key to have a line break so please lemme know how to add line breaks while adding comment to stackoverflow